# How to capture a running .Net process to disk?

Tags: .net, debugging

I'd like to perform a crash dump of a running .Net process, that hasn't actually crashed, for later debugging.  How can I do this?

It's a .Net 4 app running in Windows 2k3.

Comment: Minidump debugging for a managed app sucks rocks the size of Rocky Mountain boulders.  You'd have to be desperate.  Attaching a managed debugger is far superior.  But try it, google sos.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: At this point I would recommend using procdump instead because it supports a lot of additional options for when to capture the dump.

For a crash dump your best option is probably adplus from [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx). It automates attaching the cdb debugger and creating dump file(s) when an unhandled exception(s) occurs. You can even instruct it to create dumps for all first chance exceptions as well if you need to. The syntax is straight forward, so to take a crash dump of a process call `app.exe` you would do something like

```
adplus -crash -pn app.exe -o <output dir>
```

Once you have the dump, you can load it into WinDbg, load SOS and look at the exception using the `!threads` and `!printexception` commands.

If you're interested there are a couple of videos on Channel 9 with debugging demos. One of the demos is a crash dump.

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/MDCC-TechTalk-Advanced-NET-Debugging-part-1

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/MDCC-TechTalk-Advanced-NET-Debugging-part-2

(Full disclosure: I'm the presenter in the videos, so pardon the shameless plug).

Answer (score 1):

I installed denbugging tools for window and used ADPlus with the -hang setting

Comment: A hang dump will give you an immediate snapshot of the process. This can be very useful in many cases, but it will generally not help you troubleshoot a crash. For that a crash dump is more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Process Dumper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=E089CA41-6A87-40C8-BF69-28AC08570B7E&displaylang=en) to do this for any user-mode process.

> The User Mode Process Dumper
>   (userdump) dumps any running Win32
>   processes memory image on the fly,
>   without attaching a debugger, or
>   terminating target processes.

I think debuggability of dumps generated like this is limited to WinDbg.  You won't get the full Visual Studio ease of use.  There is info [here](http://delog.wordpress.com/2010/09/10/post-mortem-debugging-of-net-applications-using-windbg/) on postmortem debugging of dumps from managed apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [windbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) to generate a memory dump.

See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2007/01/11/how-to-install-windbg-and-get-your-first-memory-dump.aspx) blog entry on how to do this.