# Can't get debugging to work: .NET 4.0, Windows 2003 server

Tags: .net, debugging, console

I have a .NET 4.0 console application running on a production server. The app is run on an ad-hoc basis, is compiled as a debug build and all debug symbols are sent up to the server with the exe.

When an exception is raised in the app, I expect that it will die ungracefully and print the stack to the console like any old console app should.  Instead, the behavior I see is this:

1. The JIT debugger window appears, asking to debug.
2. If I say "yes", it fires up some extremely limited version of VS 2005.  I'm dumped into assembly language and cannot see the source code or the name of the file. This is the case for all levels of the stack trace.
3. If I say "no", no information is written to the console at all.

I've tried running this in both a powershell shell and a traditional cmd console with the same effect.

The server runs ASP.NET 4.0 and has no trouble returning those errors to the browser.

What I desire is to simply see the true error and the stack printed to the console without the JIT popping up. Aside from a global catch and write, what are my options?

Comment: Are you running under an account with admin permissions?

Comment: Please see my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346970/how-to-capture-a-running-net-process-to-disk/4350019#4350019 for how to generate a crash dump, which can be inspected in the debugger.

Comment: Yes, account is administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
        throw new Exception("test");
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, I know I can do this. I'm more interested in why I cannot simply see a failure like I can in most other environments.

Comment: Unhandled exception handling has changed in .NET 4.0.  Target 3.5 to see the difference.

Comment: Can't spend any more time on this, and this is easy enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use Windbg to debug and analyze the application:
http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx

You can use SOSEX extension for managed debugging in Windbg:
http://www.stevestechspot.com/